# Range of composite function method

Tags: functions, function-and-relation-composition

Let $f(x)$ and $g(x) $be functions I've made a method to find range of $f(g(x))$

---

$$
f(x)=
\begin{cases}
2+x,&   0\leq x<2\\
x^2,& 2\leq x<4
\end{cases}
$$

$$
g(x)=
\begin{cases}
1+x,&   0\leq x<1\\
3-x,& 2\leq x<5
\end{cases}
$$

---

Now to find the range what I did was put $g(x)$ in $f(x)$ and find intersection of function and x
Like putting

---

> 1. 2+(1+x)......0<=(1+x)<2  and 0<=x=<1
> 2. Taking the intersection I got this function will be satisfactory for 0=<x<1.
>    Apparently the answer isnt coming sme and I'm not able to figure out what is wrong in my method . Is there any simpler method

Comment: Range of $g(x)$ is $(-2,2)$, but $f$ does not accept negative values. How come $f(g(x))$ is define?

Comment: From what you describe your are not calculating the range but the domain (talking about $x$). In this case you missed some values $2\le x\le 3$ in addition to $0\le x<1$. Note that calculating the domain is indeed the first step in calculating the final range.

Comment: Have a look at the graph https://www.desmos.com/calculator/orlvgygmgy

Comment: @zwim is there a quick hint for how to solve

Answer (score 1):

Step 1: examine the range of $g$

- if $x\in[0,1)$ then $g(x)\in A=$ ?

> $A=[1,2)$

- if $x\in[2,5)$ then $g(x)\in B=$ ?

> $B=[-2,1)$

Step 2: intersect the range of $g$ with the domain of $f$

- $C=(A\cup B)\cap[0,4)=$ ?

> $C=[-2,2)\cap[0,4)=[0,2)$

Step 3: the final range is $R=f(C)=$ ?

> $R=[2,4)$

Bonus: it is not asked but the domain of $f\circ g$ is $D=g^{-1}(C)=$ ?

> this part is a bit more difficult
> $C=[0,2)=[0,1)\cup[1,2)$
>
> the first output interval $[0,1)$ is covered by $B$ so we search antecedents $x$ in $[2,5)$, this is the subset $(2,3]$
>
> the second output interval $[1,2)$ is exactly $A$ so antecedents $x$ are the whole $[0,1)$
>
> therefore $D=[0,1)\cup(2,3]$